# Is it okay to ask for code improvement / simplification approaches?

Tags: discussion, questions, scope

I am wondering quiet often, if I just could post my code and ask for improvement / simplification approaches on SO.
I am still not a beast in JS and other languages. Lets take the example: I successfully coded something, everything is working fine and I'm satisfied. Is it possible then to go to SO and ask what I could've done better/easier/...?
I mean, I am not asking anyone to code something for me. I am just asking for approaches how to improve or shorten my code.
Is that allowed and "community-accepted"?

Comment: You better ask such at SE Code Review.

Answer (score 3):

No.  SO is for specific questions with a single correct answer, and that wouldn't qualify as such.

Depending on how the question is structured, it *could* be on topic on Code Review, but see there guidelines before asking.

Comment: Didn't even know of the community "Code Review". So many SE communities already. Thanks!